# SHORTEST possible time

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

[image: Question]

Here's my solution
[image: my solution]

I don't know what mistake I have done but I always get the same imaginary solution.

Can you please solve and check or suggest something?

Comment: Why $\,-x/5\,$ ?

Comment: @dxiv yeah got it. I differentiated that (6-x) term wrongly. It would be -1

Answer (score 1):

[image: solution]

Here's. The solution. I by mistake wrongly differentiated the (6-x)/5 term.

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @Utkarsh: I upvoted your posts because you showed us your efforts and presented a solution after you have found it and your hand writing was very readable and you are a new user.  Nevertheless I hope you will  use MathJax the next time.

Comment: A question you could think about: Assume that you did not make an error when calculating the first derivative and it has not additional zero. What would be the consequences?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes I learnt how to use it and I have used it in my latest question. Thank you for mentioning about it

Comment: @miracle173 Surely I would use MathJax from now. Also thanks for those kind words.